# Flutter GridView in modal bottom sheet?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am in the process of programming an app using a ModalBottomSheet.
I put the core of this in another widget, because a ModalBottomSheet is not stateful, but the widget has to be stateful. This has already worked with one slider, but now I need a horizontal GridView. As soon as I put it in, it only shows me the background of the ModalBottomSheet, nothing more.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
class _MyStatefulWidget extends State<NormalSecondStep> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          'Only a text',
        ),
        SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02),
        GridView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
              maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
              childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 20,
              mainAxisSpacing: 20),
          children: [
            // Some widgets
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm, Do you want gridview in model bottom sheet in the horizontal direction right?

Comment: Uhm, yes, I want it in the horizontal direction.